# Explode or move meshes away from center

Tags: javascript, three.js, tesselation

I am trying to move all the meshes ,of which the loaded obj file is made of, away from each other so that user can see all the meshes.

I am trying to mimic the following example

[Demo](https://myhub.autodesk360.com/ue2b6101f/g/shares/SHabee1QT1a327cf2b7a18118b8b1a7ab82b?viewState=NoIgbgDAdAjCA0IAmAjAnAMxkmBmAtAEwAsAxgGz7GErH5owQb4CmA7GkoQBwCGArP2IxuIALpA)

Go to the link click on explode icon in the UI tray and move the slider.

**What Have I done So Far**
I have access to all the meshes of the model
So I can apply any function on them.
So far I have looped through them and gave them random position vector.

It works fine and the whole model explodes so that every mesh is separately visible.

**The Problem**

By giving random position vector they obviously move to random place. I want to move them exactly like the shared link. Any help would be appreciated. 
I am new to this awesome threejs and I would really love to learn more.
Thanks in Advance

**Edit**
Example Code

```
    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
for(var i = 0; i < mainStand.children.length; i++)
{
    pos1 = getRandomArbitrary(1 , 2);
    pos2 = getRandomArbitrary(1 , 2);
    pos3 = getRandomArbitrary(1 , 2);
    mainStand.children[i].position.set(pos1 , pos2 , pos3);
}
```

Where `mainStand` is the loaded obj Model

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: @NathanP. Edited the question. This works fine. the model explodes but not as cool as in the demo. I don't want the animation or anything but every mesh should move the direction it is facing. That's it

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is ? Do you need the mathematical expression ? Did you tried increasing `x`, `y`, `z` by `1` each steps to see what happens ?

Comment: if every meshe's xyz are increased by the same amount then no mesh will move away from each other rather it would move the entire model. every mesh should move away from each other not move in the same direction
@NathanP.

Comment: Yes I know that, but since you seem to be aware of that, I still don't understand what you are _really_ asking. Your code works well, you seem to understand it, so you're seeking the algorithm, am I right ?

Comment: @NathanP. what I want is what is what is working in the demo link bro.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to move every mesh *away* from the center position. This is done by calculating the vector between the mesh position and the center, and then move the mesh along this direction:

```
var center = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var distanceToMove = 0.1;

for (var i = 0; i < mainStand.children.length; i++) {
    var meshPosition = mainStand.children[i].position;

    var direction = meshPosition.clone().sub(center).normalize();

    var moveThisFar = direction.clone().multiplyScalar(distanceToMove);

    mainStand.children[i].position.add(moveThisFar);
}
```

Comment: difference is undefined! Can you please re-check you code.
explosionDirection is also undefined

Comment: I fixed the code now. This should work @UzumakiNaruto

Comment: Nope It doesn't do anything. Returns vector (0,0,0).
Can you recheck your code again please

Comment: Also your direction variable is a vector 3 with xyz as NaN.

Comment: I think you have to post more of your code for us to know exactly how the solution should be written. The code I wrote works when I make my own mock version of mainStand.

But maybe you understand the algorithm used? Calculate direction vector and move along that vector? Maybe you can use that algorithm and implement it on your own?

Comment: I think Uzumaki wants us to write his algorithm.